# iOS - A view controller uiview having horizontal and vertical scrolling

Tags: ios, ios11

I am looking for some guidance on creating a view controller with uiview and scroll view that allows horizontal as well as vertical scrolling. My uiview needs to be wider and taller than the width of the iPhone so that it holds more content in both directions. 
I tried by modifying the view controller property to freeform and increasing its width and height. This does allow scrolling to happen vertical and hold more content but cannot achieve the same in horizontal direction. 
I want to create a map of a building that someone could scroll in both directions to view it completely. 
Is it possible, if so how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Content size of ScrollView, not on the size of ViewController in the Interface builder (Storyboard).

Try to add a view inside Scrollview and add Top, Bottom, Leading, Trailing constraints with that view to Superview. Along with that add width and height constraints to the view (that's added in the scroll view) and make sure that width and height constraint value is greater than the size of Window (iPhone screen).

For detail refer this link https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH101-SW2

Comment: Thanks for your response. It helped. I think the key to get this working was having the correct constraints. I used reset to suggested constraints for the scroll view and it subview before placing more content on it. This worked for me.